# Giving access to Databricks access connector Blob contributor role in terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

How do i give access to a databricks access connector to my storage account using terraform. the below code gives error saying principal id is not guid

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "databricks_connector_role_assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.databricks_cdf_audit_access_connector.id
}
```

There is no principal_id attribute available for databricks access connector. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/databricks_access_connector

and here is my databricks connector resource definition:

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_access_connector" "databricks_cdf_audit_access_connector" {
  name                = "databricks-cdf-connector"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.cdf_audit_log_rg.name
  location            = var.databricks_location

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    service     = var.service
    team        = var.team
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Unity Catalog docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#--step-2-grant-the-managed-identity-access-to-the-storage-account) you don't grant access to the connector, but rather to managed identity assigned to that connector. In Terraform managed identities are exposed under [`identity`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/databricks_access_connector#identity) block.

Assuming you use system-assigned managed identity:

```
principal_id = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.databricks_cdf_audit_access_connector.identity[0].principal_id
```

Comment: It gives error as "Block type "identity" is represented by a list of objects, so it must be
│ indexed using a numeric key, like .identity[0]." I have provided the definition for databricks connector in the question now

Comment: identity[0] should I try that? I am not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: Yes, my typo, I updated the answer.